# How do you remove numbers from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, text, preg-replace

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\\/-a-z\s]/i', '', $text);
```

I have this expression, which removes everything except dashes, forward slashes and whitespace. However, it always leaves the numbers no matter what I move around. 
Any ideas?

$text = "FLAMBOYANT#_45/ADJ" = result = FLAMBOYANT45/ADJ

Comment: it would be easier to define what you want left.

Comment: I need everything gone except letters, forward slashes, dashes and spaces. This expression should do that - except the numbers are still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `-` that you want to match in your regex. The first hyphen `-` in the character class part of your regex has special meaning. It will be generating a range from `/` to `a` (I think). To ammend, try:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\\/\-a-z\s]/i', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
$text = preg_replace('#[^\\/\-a-z\s]#i', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

My PHP-Fu isn't that strong but I suspect that the `/-a-z` is being interpreted as the character range from `/` to `z` (and note that numbers immediately follow the slash in ASCII) so maybe you want this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\\/\-a-z\s]/i', '', $text);
```

I just added a backslash to escape the (sometimes) special meaning of "-" in a regular expression character class.

Comment: amazing it worked. i had no idea dash was a metacharacter. i have this list of metacharacters regex. .^*+?{{}\|()} also not on this list is forward slash.

Comment: @user723220: The hyphen is a special only inside character classes such as `[a-z]` where it is used to denote character ranges. However, if the hyphen is at the beginning or end of the character class, `[-a]` or `[z-]`, then it is just a literal hyphen. The slash isn't special *inside* a regex but it is often used to *delimit* a regex (`/pancake/` for example), some regex engines allow you to use different delimiters (such as this Perl: `$x =~ m!^http://!`) to avoid a mess of incomprehensible "toothpicks" like `/\\\//`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $text = "FLAM-BOYANT#_45/ADJ";
  $allowed = "/[^a-z\\040\\.\\-\/]/i";
  $text=  preg_replace($allowed,"",$text);
  echo $text; //FLAM-BOYANT/ADJ
?>
```